# DBUnit fulltext search support

Tags: java, mysql, mocking, spring-boot, dbunit

I am trying to test a REST service which queries restaurant data from a MySQL database with DBUnit and MockMvc. **All tests work except the ones where full text search is executed. These always return no results.** Test example:

```
@Test
public void searchRestaurantsForSimpleName() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/restaurants?query=first").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.restaurantList[0].name").value("first"));
}
```

DAO code which is executed and not returning any results is:

```
@Query(value = "select *, match(search1) against(?1 in boolean mode) as score1," + ...
```

MySQL engine type is **InnoDB**, which supports fulltext search only when index is built. Could the problem be that DBUnit doesn't rebuild the index, therefore it gets no search results?

Do you have any other ideas where the problem could be or how to make a test for  fulltext search?

**Edit (more code):**

RestaurantDao, whole query:

```
public interface RestaurantDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Restaurant, Long> {

//native query does not support pagination, which has to be done manually

@Query(value = "select *," +
        " match(search1) against(?1 in boolean mode) as score1," +
        " match(search2) against(?1 in boolean mode) as score2" +
        " from restaurant r where" +
        " (?2 is null or rating_point >= ?2)" +
        " and (?3 is null or rating_point <= ?3)" +
        " and (?4 is null or rating_bottle = ?4)" +
        " and (?5 is null or ?5 = FALSE or accommodation = ?5)" +
        " and (?6 is null or ?6 = FALSE or garden = ?6)" +
        " and (?7 is null or rating_star = ?7)" +
        " and (?8 is null or oecar = ?8)" +
        " and (?9 = TRUE or hidden = ?9)" +
        " having (length(?1) = 0 or score1 > 0 or score2 > 0)" +
        " order by score1 desc, score2 desc, rating_point desc, rating_star desc, oecar asc, name asc" +
        " limit ?10 offset ?11", nativeQuery = true)
List<Restaurant> fullTextSearch(
        String query,
        Integer minRating,
        Integer maxRating,
        Integer bottleRating,
        Boolean accommodation,
        Boolean garden,
        Integer stars,
        Integer oecar,
        boolean includeHidden,
        int limit,
        int offset
);
```

MySQL table, which was automatically created by hibernate (i excluded some field for readability):

```
restaurant | CREATE TABLE `restaurant` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accommodation` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `garden` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hidden` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kitchen_chef` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oecar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_point` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_star` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `search1_hidx` (`search1`),
  KEY `search2_hidx` (`search2`),
  KEY `accommodation_hidx` (`accommodation`),
  KEY `garden_hidx` (`garden`),
  KEY `seats_hidx` (`seats`),
  KEY `rating_star_hidx` (`rating_star`),
  KEY `oecar_hidx` (`oecar`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_search1` (`search1`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_search2` (`search2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=909 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

DBUnit datase definition

```
<dataset>
    <restaurant id="1" name="first" search1="first" search2="wien test" garden="true" accommodation="true" seats="50" rating_point="90" rating_bottle="2" rating_star="5" oecar="3" hidden="false" />
    ...
</dataset>
```

Comment: Does your query work when you throw it at the database?
Also, can we have the rest of the query and the table structure

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes of course, query works fine also the rest service which is using the query works fine when deployed to tomcat or started with spring boot. Therefore I do not think that the problem is in the query itself, but has something to do with mocking. (Anyway I am extending my question to include more details).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what data you mean. I am using DBUnit for mocking my database and the restaurant with id 1 (last code block) is exactly the same as I have in my tests.

Comment: Good question, this part is missing in the code samples. There is a rest service (@RestController) implementation and one method which calls that dao. This method has many @RequestParam(s) and for pagination there are default values set (limit 20, offset 0). Other params are set as not required and passed as null if missing. Thats why you can see in this sql query checks like "?6 is null or ....". Pagination should not be the issue since tests for getting all restaurants work fine without explicitly setting pagination values.

Comment: I am using InnoDB engine: "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair". (Edit) I can try to drop and recreate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94616/discussion-between-janschweizer-and-robin).